# Is it possible for humans to absorb nutients from the soil similar to trees?

Tags: nutrition

Recently heard about a practice where the pores of skin are expanded by steam or pierced with small holes. The body or portion of is then submersed or lathered in a nutrient solution for absorption ***inside the body***. I can't find much evidence for or against the practice but in any case, still leads to the question.

Given we have some of the most [fertile](https://www.doi.gov/sites/doi.gov/files/uploads/olympic_national_park._photo_by_adam_jewell._ste.jpg) and [nutrient rich soil](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi08L-ZreDsAhXjJzQIHfPCCuIQFjALegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nrcs.usda.gov%2FInternet%2FFSE_DOCUMENTS%2Fnrcs144p2_034094.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3zHxW_L9vWm9XLCJ6aDTqY) here in the North West:

- Is it possible for the human body to absorb nutrients, minerals and water, specifically from the earth's soil via some sort of contact or submersion, similar to the way roots of a tree work ?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: On top of what @CareyGregory has said I am specifically intrigued as to where you recently heard of such practices. This is reminiscent of a sci-fi Swedish TV series I recently watched called Jordskott.